# UIView with UILabel subview - responding to AutoLayout changes

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview

I've got a UIView with a UILabel subview that has constraints defined like so:

```
        constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[_messageLabel]-50-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
        [self addConstraints:constraints];
        constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[_messageLabel]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
        [self addConstraints:constraints];
```

In certain instances, the label is not big enough to show all the text, so it is truncated.
When I adjust the size of the UIView within an animation block, the label animates its change in size as appropriate. However, the re-drawing of the text within it kind of 'jumps' -- and fair enough, i wouldn't expect the label to animate a change in the internal drawing of its text.

Anyway, what I'd like to do is fade out this label and perhaps fade in a second to avoid this jerkiness.

My question: Is there a good callback on UIView as to when it will respond to an auto layout change? or is that simply done in layoutSubviews?

Comment: You could always just try to call setNeedsDisplay on the label as it is updating the animation. It should redraw itself from that.

Comment: Check this link http://www.objc.io/issue-3/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox.html